# FFMPEG extract a specific frame and output its type (I, P, B)

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm using this command to extract two specific frames

`ffmpeg -ss 00:03:00.0 -i video.mkv -vf select="eq(n\,0)+eq(n\,1)" -vsync vfr -vframes 2 %01d.bmp`

How do I know the frame type of each frame and output it to the filename directly, so the file name would be:

`"%01d-I.bmp" or "%01d-P.bmp" or "%01d-B.bmp"`

Answer (score 1):

Split the results of the first select filter into 3 outputs and use select for each of the three with a picture type selection.

`ffmpeg -ss 00:03:00.0 -i video.mkv -filter_complex "select='eq(n\,0)+eq(n\,1)',split=3[i][p][b];[i]select='eq(PICT_TYPE\,I)'[i];[p]select='eq(PICT_TYPE\,P)'[p];[b]select='eq(PICT_TYPE\,B)'[b]" -map [i] -vsync vfr %01d-I.bmp -map [p] -vsync vfr %01d-P.bmp -map [b] -vsync vfr %01d-B.bmp`